# Многофазовая сортировка Фибоначчиевая. Как это работает?

Tags: python, сортировка, числа-фибоначчи

Товарищи, прошу вашей помощи. Задание звучит следующим образом: (написать программу на языке программирования Python, позволяющую отсортировать числовой массив данных, расположенный в файле, результат загрузить в другой файл.) Если в случае создания массива, его загрузкой и выгрузкой результата всё понятно, то вот с :Многофазная сортировка (Фибоначчиевая) мне всё не понятно. Как число фибоначчи считается я смотрел:

```
fib1 = 1
fib2 = 1
n = input("Номер элемента ряда Фибоначчи: ")
n = int(n)
i = 0
while i < n - 2:
    fib_sum = fib1 + fib2
    fib1 = fib2
     fib2 = fib_sum
    i = i + 1
 
print("Значение этого элемента:", fib2)
```

Но как вообще работает сортировка Фибоначчиевая? Не смог просто напросто найти что-то похожее

Comment: в приведённом задании отсутствует текст запроса на "Фибоначчиевую сортировку". Оно: "Задание звучит следующим образом: (написать программу на языке программирования Python, позволяющую отсортировать числовой массив данных, расположенный в файле, результат загрузить в другой файл.)"

Comment: https://studfile.net/preview/4370267/page:19/#183 — как пример сойдёт?

Comment: Цитирую то, что написано выше: Если в случае создания массива, его загрузкой и выгрузкой результата всё понятно, то вот с :Многофазная сортировка (Фибоначчиевая) мне всё не понятно. В моём задании фигурирует три вида сортировок, одна из них - Фибоначчиевая